# Unknown error while reading AVI files in OpenCV

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, video, opencv

whenever i am trying to read out the avi file and converting into grayscal  using Opencv 2.1 and VS 2008 in windows xp

i don't why i am getting following run time error at the same time i am unable to get the help on it

**ERROR 1**

> [NULL @ 0x37da10]Invalid and
>   inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames
>   detected fps=23 frame (w, h) = (640,
>   272) Output #0, avi, to 'test.avi':
>   Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p,
>   640x272, q=2-31, 11141 kb/s, 90k tbn,
>   23 .98 tbc [mpeg4 @ 0x37f920]removing
>   common factors from framerate [mpeg4 @
>   0x37da10]Invalid and inefficient
>   vfw-avi packed B frames detected
>   Compiler did not align stack
>   variables. Libavcodec has been
>   miscompiled and may be very slow or
>   crash. This is not a bug in
>   libavcodec, but in the compiler. You
>   may try recompiling using gcc >= 4.2.
>   Do not report crashes to FFmpeg
>   developers. [mpeg4 @ 0x37da10]Invalid
>   and inefficient vfw-avi packed B
>   frames detected

if i try some other avi file then i am getting following runtime error

**ERROR 2**

> fps=15 frame (w, h) = (176, 184)
>   Output #0, avi, to 'demo.avi':
>       Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 176x184, q=2-31, 2072 kb/s,
>   90k tbn, 15 tbc Compiler did not align
>   stack variables. Libavcodec has been
>   miscompiled and may be very slow or
>   crash. This is not a bug in
>   libavcodec, but in the compiler. You
>   may try recompiling using gcc >= 4.2.
>   Do not report crashes to FFmpeg
>   developers.

I really don't know whats going on here is my code from Learning OpenCV ,

```
// VideoCon.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.


#include "stdafx.h"


#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    cvNamedWindow( "Example2_10", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvNamedWindow( "Log_Polar", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture( "Rambo.avi" );
    if (!capture){
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage* bgr_frame;
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty (
        capture,
        CV_CAP_PROP_FPS
    );
 printf("fps=%d\n",(int)fps);

    CvSize size = cvSize(
        (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
        (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    );

    printf("frame (w, h) = (%d, %d)\n",size.width,size.height);
    #ifndef NOWRITE
   CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(  
   // On linux Will only work if you've installed     ffmpeg development files correctly, 
       "test.avi",                               
    // otherwise segmentation fault.  Windows probably better.
        CV_FOURCC('D','X','5','0'),    
        fps,
        size
    );
#endif
    IplImage* logpolar_frame = cvCreateImage(
        size,
        IPL_DEPTH_8U,
        3
    );

    IplImage* gray_frame = cvCreateImage(
        size,
        IPL_DEPTH_8U,
        1
    );

    while( (bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture)) != NULL ) {
        cvShowImage( "Example2_10", bgr_frame );
        cvConvertImage(   //We never make use of this gray image
            bgr_frame,
            gray_frame,
            CV_RGB2GRAY
        );
        cvLogPolar( bgr_frame, logpolar_frame,  
           //This is just a fun conversion the mimic's the human visual system
                    cvPoint2D32f(bgr_frame->width/2,
                    bgr_frame->height/2), 
                    40, 
                    CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS );
        cvShowImage( "Log_Polar", logpolar_frame );
        //Sigh, on linux, depending on your ffmpeg, this often won't work ...
#ifndef NOWRITE
       cvWriteToAVI( writer, logpolar_frame );
#endif
        char c = cvWaitKey(10);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
#ifndef NOWRITE
    cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );
#endif
    cvReleaseImage( &gray_frame );
    cvReleaseImage( &logpolar_frame );
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my **GUESS** is that you do not have the right codecs installed on your machine.
try installing some proper codecs.

Comment: If he is able to play the video then he already has the right codec installed. I suggest you submit this question to libavcoded mailing list.

Comment: I had a very same problem afew months ago. I was able to play the movie with VLC (which has built in codecs) but the opencv gave me crap.

Comment: i have Divx codec , Xvid and ffdshow installed , now m really frustrate don't know what else required